# Wrinkled geometry

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

My geometry has this "wrinkle" at the corner when I apply the subdivision surface modifier.
Can anyone help why this happens, please?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try making the edge loops flow around the shape.
Somethig like this. I think it'll work better when you subdivide.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try this.